# Video/Photo effect on many bootstrap sites

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm  building a bootstrap site and I need help identifying the effects that I see being used for top images. Sometimes it's a moving video like this [site](http://involvio.com.).

Another example is just a filtered effect over the photo making it look dark or blurry.

What is this and how can I get my hero image to have this look on my bootstrap site.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

He is using following Class:

```
body.marketing.is-home .hero:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  content: "";
  background: rgba(205, 35, 42, 0.9);
  z-index: 2;
}
```